# The prefix "android" for attribute "android:id" associated with an element type "ListView" is not bound

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4.5

I keep getting this error

The prefix "android" for attribute "android:id" associated with an element type "ListView" is not bound.

bit of code where the error is

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

It works when this code isnt in the first veiw state when in flex as If i create another component the code works But I need it in the homeview to display the list of items the id is refering to but keeps saying undefined state

`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <s:List
        android:id="@+id/Games"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </s:List>
    </LinearLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the @android:id/list to @+id/list

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

This should work!

Comment: still getting the error but added abit more detail into my other comment